# Why does my cursor stop in the middle of a backup loop?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Why does my cursor stop in the middle of a backup loop? It will say it’s completed the whole process with no errors even though not all databases have been backed up to a location which I specified in the script. The number of backed up files varies every time I execute the script.

I'm trying to backup databases to a location without appending the name of the backup file with a "_backup_date_&_time_stamp" and the only way do to is to script it out. SQL Server’s "maintenance plans" tool doesn’t support that capability.

Below is my query to backup hundreds of SQL Server databases.

```
--Run this on the source SQL Server's master database---
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup

--Specify database backup directory. Backup directly to the destination server directory
SET @path = '\\<Server>\<FolderPath>\'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT NAME 
    FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases 
    WHERE NAME like 'DB%'

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
      SET @fileName = @path + @name + '.BAK'  

      BACKUP DATABASE @name TO DISK = @fileName WITH INIT

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Answer (score 1):

Congratualtions, this is one of the valid reasons to use a cursor!! I would suggest you create the backup statements rather than run them and see exactly what your cursor told it to backup.

```
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE @path VARCHAR(256) -- path for backup files
DECLARE @fileName VARCHAR(256) -- filename for backup

--Specify database backup directory. Backup directly to the destination server directory
SET @path = '\\<Server>\<FolderPath>\'

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT NAME FROM master.dbo.sysdatabases WHERE NAME like 'DB%'

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   


WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN   
      SET @fileName = @path + @name + '.BAK'  
      PRINT 'BACKUP DATABASE ' +@name+ ' TO DISK = ' + @fileName + '  WITH INIT'

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @name   
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Now you can analyse what was created and even try to run the statements and see what happens. I don't see any try catch blocks, so maybe you are getting some errors that are not bubbling up.

Comment: The output is the same number of databases that I'm trying to backup, which means it's completing the backup. I think there's a resource issue behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The output is the same number of databases that I'm trying to backup, which means it's completing the backup. I think there's a resource issue behind this.

Can you or someone modify the script to forcibly backup all databases specified in the where clause?